# Web Based Event Bar Timeline

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Sorry for the vague title, but I am struggling to even tell you what I exactly need.  I am looking to make an event timeline.  The final product is something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKwYE.jpg

I am not sure what you even call that.  The green is a running status and the other colors represent other various events that have happened for the specific location and the durations of all the events.  If that makes sense.  Maybe if I even knew what to Google I would be ok. I am thinking there is something out there that does this, I just can't find it.

Thanks for any input you have on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [DayPiolt](http://www.daypilot.org/). I've used it on some previous projects and it's very effective and almost similar to the image you linked (possibly the closest is [scheduler](http://www.daypilot.org/scheduler/)). Even if it doesn't offer exactly what you want, it's a starting point to find something more suitable.